# Simple Functionality of Previous and Next Intents in the same Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to Android programming.
Could anyone help me out with the Functionality of Previous and Next Intents in the same Android Activity?

I am building a Quotes App.
So, I have all my Quotes neatly stored in a **String Array** for now.

All I need to do is **loop through the String Array in a Back & Forth manner.**

I tried using a **For/While Loop**, however, I kept getting errors that I have to have my iterator variable "i" as Final.

Hence, I used the **Iterator type** & I'm able to move Forward neatly.
However, moving back is a problem. I do not know how to achieve it via Iterator type.

Also, the app crashes at the end of the String Array (Although I have a catch exception block).

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     try
          {
           

final String[] myStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DayOfWeek);
final List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myStringArray));
final Iterator<String> it = myArray.iterator();

View prevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
View nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);

final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TAG", "prevButton tapped");
       //How Can I move back the String Array?
    }
});

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TAG", "nextButton tapped");

        //Using Iterator
        if(it.hasNext()) {
            //refreshTextView();
            tv.setText(it.next());
            Log.d("WhichString", it.next());

           //Once I reach the end, the app crashes :(
        }
    }
});
} catch(Exception e) {
    //Exception block useless as of now
    Log.e("MyApp", "exception", e);
}    
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Had to keep this block as it was looking for it in the code.
    //Although this is not required.

     Log.d("Test","hi");
}
```

---

I tried @Nasser's solution.
But when I run the code, I get this error.

...
05-25 08:23:59.492: W/dalvikvm(1060): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.adworks.quotes/com.adworks.quotes.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at com.adworks.quotes.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:15)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-25 08:23:59.512: E/AndroidRuntime(1060):     ... 11 more

I am calling my String Array in this manner.

```
                nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    textOut = myStringArray[getCount()];

                    tv.setText(textOut);


            }
```

Comment: Don't use an iterator, simply use an `int` value to represent the current position and in the two `OnClickListeners` simply increment/decrement that value and get the quote from the list using that position indicator. You'll also need to insert some checks so you don't overstep the boundaries of the array/list.

Comment: I tried to reformat but you are missing some code. (where is the try (of the try catch)

Comment: @RvdK - Just added the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use a int variable for storing your current position like @Luksprog said.

somthing like

```
private int quotesCount = 0;
```

and when click on NextButton

```
myArray.get(getCount());
```

use some method to calculate current count;

```
public int getCount() {
        if (myArray.size() > 0){
            if (quotesCount == myArray.size() - 1) {
                quotesCount = 0;
            } else {
                quotesCount++;
            }
        }
        return quotesCount;
    }
```

its not fully working, just some idea how to do it.